# Centering vertically in the viewcontroller with navigationbar in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, ios-autolayout

I tried to center an UIImageView in my UIViewController which has a navigation bar at the top and what I wanna do is to have my UIImageView centered between the bottom of the navigationbar and the bottom of the view (with constraints of course). But Xcode make it vertically centered in the view from top of the view (centered between top of the navigationbar and bottom of the UIViewcontroller).

Is there a way to do what I wanna do? with constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `UIView` (empty) with constraints with top and bottom layout guide. Then add your `UIImageView` as a subview and align vertically and horizontally.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []` inside `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `UIViewController` in embedded in a `UINavigationController` then you should be able to make the center of your `UIImageView` equal to the center of the `UIViewController`'s view. Otherwise if you added the nav bar manually you will need to offset the center Y coordinate of the `UIImageView` by the height of the nav bar.

Comment: It's Embedded in; But it's not centered as I said.